# Formula to highlight if difference is over a certain percentage?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column that I need to apply conditional formatting to.

The condition is based on two columns: `Total` and `Difference`.

`Total` - Show a total count of records from last month.
`Difference` - This is a positive or negative number indicating how many more or fewer records there are this month.

I am trying to determine if there is more than a 15% and 30% difference and highlight the cell accordingly.

As such, I have two formulas:

```
=(ABS($Q5)/$P5) > 0.15
```

and

```
=(ABS($Q5)/$P5) > 0.3
```

[image]

The problem is that, while it appears to work for the first condition, it does not go one to evaluate the second one and override the formatting of the first:

[image]

The second row shows a `Total` of **1057** and a `Difference` of **-333**. The formula for the second condition should evaluate to `true` as `333 / 1057 = 0.315`.

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: (this is just a shot in the dark) What happens if you check "Stop If True" for the *second* formula?

Comment: No change. However, that lead me to move the 2nd formula to the top of the list, with "Stop If True" checked.  And that does work.

Comment: So, my problem is semi-solved, but I still don't understand why it wouldn't work the way I had it...

Comment: The rules are applied "in order", so it will try the first, then the second and so on. You might need to put the rules in reserve order of preference.

Comment: As far -333 is concern is satisfying both >15% and 30% so that it's overriding ! Could you share the formula U are using for Difference?